# PKI certificate based authentication using Angular and Spring Boot Micro-services

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am migrating our traditional MVC web application to Angular + Spring Boot micro-service and I need to do the PKI certificate based authentication for the end users.

In my traditional MVC web app I have done SSL configuration at tomcat level and did several other configurations and that did the magic to have PKI certificate based authentication. Now I have this Angular 7 web app which is having Spring Boot micro-services at the backend. I have already tried redirecting the request from Angular to the Spring Boot service so that browser pops-up for the installed client certificate. Now the challenge is, I have to get the control back to the Angular UI app with that certificate information from the micro-service.

I expect that when I hit the URL then, browser pops-up for the user certificate and that certificate goes to spring boot service to authenticate and once authenticated user can now able to login to the application with appropriate roles he/she were provided with.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to send it via headers in angular using Authorization
then get it in the back and do ur work try to create a service in the front in each call you send your headers.
hope it Helps 
best regards minouche